# Django multiple apps on multiple dbs

Tags: django, django-orm

So I am working on a project where every application has its own database. However, when I sync the database, only the default database is synced. I need help to see the issue.

```
# from settings.py
try:
    from local_settings import *
    INSTALLED_APPS += LOCAL_APPS
    for app in LOCAL_APPS:
        _appdb = DATABASES['default'].copy()
        _appdb['NAME'] = app
        DATABASES[app] = _appdb
except ImportError:
    pass
```

I have already verified that each local app has a corresponding database generated dynamically. Here is the db router

```
import os

MY_LOCAL_APPS = []
with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "apps.csv")) as appsfile:
    MY_LOCAL_APPS = appsfile.readlines()

MY_LOCAL_APPS = [x.strip() for x in MY_LOCAL_APPS]

class JauntRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read app models go to app_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label in MY_LOCAL_APPS: 
            return model._meta.app_label
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write app models go to app_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label in MY_LOCAL_APPS: 
            return model._meta.app_label
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in MY_LOCAL_APPS: 
            return model._meta.app_label
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        if db in MY_LOCAL_APPS:
            return model._meta.app_label == db
        return None
```

When I run `syncdb` however, tables are created in the `default` database. Please note that I have printed out the `INSTALLED_APPS` and `DATABASES` from the settings file and they appear correct so I don't think that is the issue.

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the --database switch of syncdb.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/multi-db/#synchronizing-your-databases